# Why is iSpatialFilter in an "Add-in" crashing ArcMap on Partial or Full refresh?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, development

I am building a tool in my Add-in that is partially based on a .Net sample and partially on my former VBA tool. (Both work)

My problem is that I would like to be able to only select features from the current layer in the TOC. For this i have to use iFeatureSelection:SelectFeatures with iSpatialFilter. This works flawlessly in VBA but not in my .Net Add-in

ArcMap crashes when I refresh / partial refresh the map.

Any ideas?

```
pGeoFeatureLayer.Selectable = True

pFeatureSelection = pGeoFeatureLayer

pEnv = m_pFeedbackEnv.Stop()

With pSpatialFilter
    .GeometryField = "Shape"
    .Geometry = pEnv
    .SpatialRel = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects
End With

If Not arg.Shift Then
    pFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures(pSpatialFilter, ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultNew, False)
Else
    pFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures(pSpatialFilter, ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriSelectionResultEnum.esriSelectionResultAdd, False)
End If

m_focusMap.PartialRefresh(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to tell from the incomplete code sample, but I get the impression ArcMap crashes because of an unhandled exception in your .NET code. I suggest catching the exception to find out what error is actually ocurring.

Assuming the last line is the place your code crashes, I guess it could probably be a NullRefenceException when calling PartialRefresh method on the (possibly null) m_focusMap object.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments below, the issue was that the **display feedback needs to be canceled** before refreshing the active view.

Comment: Cannot trap the error; application crashes on the refresh line. m_focusMap is not null. dll compiles without errors. ArcMap crashed with the compiled add-in as well as when debugging

Comment: Does it also crash without the prior call to SelectFeatures?

Comment: I should add that when using the FocusMap.SelectByShape method, everything works fine. It's only when i try to select featues from a specific layer via iFeatureSelection:SelectFeatures when i encounter the crash. (Envelope geometry passed into the spatial filter is not null or empty, the same spatial filter successfully returns feature count from the underlying feature class)

Comment: crashes on this line:m_focusMap.PartialRefresh(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGeoSelection, Nothing, Nothing)
Also crashes with the full refresh method: m_focusMap.Refresh

Comment: Yes also crashed without invoking the SelectFeatures method

Comment: Ok, this is when hunting for errors like this becomes a trial-and-error :-) First, I would try without the display feedback as this is most likely to be a display-related issue. Second, try calling IFeatureSelection.SelectionChanged after altering the selection, but I do not think it will help... Third, I have no other idea :-)

Comment: I will try without the display feedback, i am sure the selection is changing, strangely i can see the selection for a flash before it crashes.  For now i get this line in the immediate window as soon as the debuggin process starts and application strarts: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Add_Ins_CustomUIElements.dll

Comment: Got it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Apparently feedback has to be canceled before invoking Refresh

Comment: I am glad you got it. Just out of curiosity, how do you cancel a display feedback other than invoking the Stop() method?

Comment: set feedback to nothing

Comment: That is a very weird behavior, since setting a RCW reference to null has no immediate effect on its COM object destruction, which does not happen until the garbage collector kicks in (or until you release the object via Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject)...

Comment: Yes wierd, I thought so too... As per your suggestion I was trying things with the display feedback and while doing so noticed that in the ESRI sample it is set to nothing prior to invoking the refresh on the Active View. (was normally doing so after refresh in my VBA script with no issues) This alone mysteriously solved the crashing problem. Not the first time I saw errors not being trapped...  Mind you i am using the Express edition and this is an ESRI Add-On...